# Headphones randomly turn off and music dies

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

I have been experiencing a strange problem with my Nokia BH-503 Bluetooth Headset. I will be listening to music or watching YouTube or something and Randomly the audio will just cut out and all videos will stop.  When I turn off my headset the audio and or video will start again.  I don't know if it is my headset or what.

How does the audio/video know to stop? There are controls on the headset/keyboard and they don't do anything. How is the audio/video cutting out when I can't even control the audio/video with my headset/keyboard?